# Silverlight DatePicker in DataGrid allow NULL dates

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

I have a DataGrid that has as one of its columns a `DatePicker` (for the editing template). Is there a way to keep this but still allow a user to enter in a NULL date?

Answer (score 5):

Do the following (in Silverlight 4):

1) Bound property of DataContext must be Nullable (or Datetime?)

2) In XAML set TargetNullValue='' of binding property something like:

```
Text="{Binding DocumentDate, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd', TargetNullValue=''}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this while researching same problem. This is how I fixed it since it hasn't been marked.

I have used converter which converts value to `null` if it is just an empty datatime object.

```
public class DateTimeToNullConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(); 
            if (dt.Equals(value)) return null; 
            return value;
        } 
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        { 
            return value; 
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentContractRenewal.ExpiryDate, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToNullConverter}}"
```